# Should I run multiple instances of qtminer for multiple GPUs?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, gpu, qtminer

I am using qtminer from ethpool for mining with a single card. I want to add extra cards to the rig, should I start a new instance of qtminer for every card or should I start a single instance of qminer with extra parameters for every singe GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start a new instance for each card, and use the `--opencl-platform` flag to specify which card each instance will use. For example:

`qtminer.exe -s us2.ethpool.org:3333 -u Wallet Add .rig1 --opencl-platform`1

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what this is doing to answer the question.